# How can I limit the bandwidth over an SSHFS mount?

Tags: mount, bandwidth, bandwidth-control, sshfs, fuse

I am transfering large media files to my local machine over an SSHFS mount. I am not too concerned about speed and want to provide a better QOS to other network services and so want to limit the bandwidth for these transfers.

I can't seem to find an option for this in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs) - how can I achieve this?

```
# uname -a
Linux core1 4.19.68-coreos #1 SMP Wed Sep 4 02:59:18 -00 2019 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a combination of iptables MARK to tag traffic to/from port 22 and traffic control `tc` to limit the egress rate of matched packets using a suitable qdisc.

An easier if less flexible way to get this working would be to pipe your sending process through `pv` (pipe viewer) using the --rate-limit and --buffer-size switches: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv. You don't say if you're using a cli command like `cp` or `rsync`, or a gui desktop drag-and-drop to transfer your files. Using `pv` is likely a nonstarter if you're using a gui.

Comment: 2 very cool answers, I'm using [sonarr](https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr) so I guess just cp from the filesystem's perspective - I'll try the first one as the second one would be tricky with sonarr

Comment: Could you post an example for `tc` and/or add more relevant documentation?